# Excel- Llenar valores en múltiples celdas extraidas de una pagina distinta cuando un valor se escribe

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Caso:
En Hoja1 Hay 300 empleados (1 por fila) con datos como nombre, numero de empleado, posición, etc. en A1,B1,C1, etc.

En Hoja2 hay una plantilla para crear una credencial de empleado, donde se encontraban celdas vacías para escribir los datos de Nombre, Numero de empleado, posición, etc.

La función que busco permitía que, al escribir el [Numero de Empleado] en una celda específica (digamos J3), se llenaran automáticamente las demás celdas vacías con los datos del empleado.

Es decir, al escribir "1" en la celda J3 de Hoja2, las celdas B3 y H3 se llenaban con los datos del Empleado con Número de Empleado 1, es decir, A1 y B1.
Y si se escribía "200",se llenaba B3 y H3 con los datos de A200 y B200, o con los datos de la fila donde se encontrase el Numero de Empleado 200.

Asumo que es una función BUSCAR, pero no recuerdo cual, ni como operacionalizarla.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La fórmula que necesitas se llama `BUSCARV`.

> [Cómo usar
>   BUSCARV](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Funci%C3%B3n-BUSCARV-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Básicamente, en tu Hoja dos buscarás un argumento **que sea único para cada empleado** (en tu ejemplo, entiendo que es `número de empleado`, y recuperarás el valor de dicha fila, pero en la columna que tú especifiques (la columna nombre, la columna posición, etc.).

Tu fórmula debería tener más o menos este aspecto:

```
=BUSCARV(Numero de empleado;lugar de tus datos; nº columna que te interesa;FALSO)
```

Si tienes problemas, pon algunos datos de ejemplo, y vemos como construir la fórmula.